# combine first and last name in access

Tags: database, ms-access

I am working on a database and I would like to combine the first 4 letters of the last name and the first 2 letters of the first name to create a UserID of sorts that can be used to Identify the User

For example

`John Smith`
would be `SMITJO`

would this be possible

I am new to Access and databases any help would be great

Comment: Are the first name/last name stored in separate fields? How will you differentiate between "Joan Smith" and "John Smith", as both will be known as "SMITJO"? And how will you deal with changes of surname?

Comment: As Applecore pointed out this approach has a very high potential to cause duplicates. The best way to create a unique user ID that never changes in the system and does not rely on names (that could change if someone marries) is a auto increasing primary key. IDs will start at a specific number eg 1000 and increase automatically by 1 for every new user. If you delete a user this number will not be re-used. This way you have real unique IDs.